# access denied searching mapped drive via windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-7, server-message-block, search

when searching a mapped drive in a windows server 2008 environment i receive an access denied error message in windows explorer.  this message happens with windows 7 professional 32-bit only.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: can you access files on this mapped drive?

Comment: Yes you can access the files on the mapped drive.  The issue only arises when doing a search on Windows 7 machines.

Comment: You didn't mention if this the windows server 2008 is a domain environment and is the windows 7 is part of the domain? This has to be share permissions issue, try to add "everyone" to the security group which can access this folder and they try to see how this the issue.